# Use Linq to SQL to search only time portions of a date in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, lambda

I want to be able to search on a DateTime field not only by a date range, but also by a time range. For example, "Get me all records in the month of May created between 1pm and 3pm". The SQL I'm looking to generated is:

```
WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN '05/01/2010' AND '06/01/2010' AND CONVERT(time(4), CreatedOn) BETWEEN '01:00 PM' AND '03:00 PM'
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get a lambda expression to get me there. Anybody got any clue? I've got System.Linq.Dynamic in my project. Similar to the way you can pass a string as an OrderBy clause, I thought I might be able to do the same with the Where method as follows::

```
results = results.Where("CONVERT(time(4), OccurredOn) BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'", Criteria.OffenseTimeStart, Criteria.OffenseTimeEnd);
```

But that throws an exception in System.Linq.Dynamic. Anybody got any pointers?

THANKS FOR THE HELP! Here is my working code excerpt. I exposed my time criteria properties as TimeSpans:

```
            if (Criteria.OffenseDateStart.HasValue)
                results = results.Where(o => o.OccurredOn >= Criteria.OffenseDateStart);

            if (Criteria.OffenseDateEnd.HasValue)
                results = results.Where(o => o.OccurredOn <= Criteria.OffenseDateEnd);

            if (Criteria.OffenseTimeStart.HasValue)
                results = results.Where(o => o.OccurredOn.TimeOfDay >= Criteria.OffenseTimeStart);

            if (Criteria.OffenseTimeEnd.HasValue)
                results = results.Where(o => o.OccurredOn.TimeOfDay <= Criteria.OffenseTimeEnd);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do a 'Between', but you can write a linq query like:

```
where (x.CreatedOn.Date >= myDate.Date && x.CreatedOn.Date <= myDate2.Date)
   && (x.CreatedOn.TimeOfDay >= TimeSpan.Parse("13:00") && x.CreatedOn.TimeOfDay <= TimeSpan.Parse("15:00"))
```

Comment: The SQL produced is a little more verbose, but works like a charm! I didn't think there was a TimeSpan SQL translation...but I guess I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I think whats produced in NHibernate 3.0 is nicer, but atleast it works :) glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
results = results.Where(x => x.OccurredOn.Date >= Criteria.OffenseDateStart.Date
         && x.OccurredOn.Date <= Criteria.OffenseDateEnd.Date
         && x.OccurredOn.TimeOfDay >= Criteria.OffenseTimeStart.TimeOfDay
         && x.OccurredOn.TimeOfDay <= Criteria.OffenseTimeEnd.TimeOfDay);
```

(Assuming that `OccurredOn`, `OffenseDateStart`, `OffenseDateEnd`, `OffenseTimeStart` and `OffenseTimeEnd` are all typed as `DateTime`.)